# Set title text on custom title bar

Tags: android, titlebar, custom-titlebar

I have to create a custom title bar, to set a dynamic text. This would be something like setting a Title, and below, the dynamic subtitle on the Actionbar.

In this case, the App title goes on the left side, as for default. The dynamic text goes in the right side, and must change dynamically.

This is the layout **custom_titlebar.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView 
    android:id="@+id/title_left_text"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="left" />

<TextView 
    android:id="@+id/title_right_text"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="right"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />    
</RelativeLayout>
```

In the **manifest** I've defined:

```
<application
    android:theme="@style/Theme.NoTitle" >
```

And on the **Activity**:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    //customTitleSupported = requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE);
        //HAVE COMENTED THIS, BECAUSE IT THROWS: You cannot combine custom titles with other title feature..

    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    getWindow().setFeatureInt(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE, R.layout.custom_titlebar);

    TextView title = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.title_left_text);
    title.setText(getTitle());
```

To change text dynamically, I also have on the **Activity**:

```
public void setTitleStatus(String right) {
    if (right.length() > 20) {
        right = right.substring(0, 20);
    }
    TextView status = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.title_right_text);

    status.setText(right);
}
```

The problem is that is throwing a NPE on the line of the onCreate where I set the title (`title.setText(getTitle());`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change

```
title.setText(getTitle().toString());
```

Comment: if is this your own getTitle() method?

Comment: I don't have getTitle() method. I supossed it was a predefined method. What would be the way to set the app title there?

Comment: UPDATE-> I've tryed setting `title.setText("TITLE")` but continues throwing NPE

Comment: Not really. Gives me the problem when defining styles. If I set in the theme: `@android.style/Theme.black` it does right. but if I set `Holo` theme then appears this on the logcat: `You cannot combine custom titles with other title feature`

Comment: The problem is  getWindow().setFeatureInt(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE, R.layout.custom_titlebar);
 here

Answer (score 0):

Look in the Android samples. In the Bluetooth project is made a custom action bar, that changes it's state in different occasions

Comment: Yes, that's the way I have it now. But I need it without the ActionBar

Comment: why do you need without ActionBar ? if you have a nice example that works, and your idea is to show a title in top of the activity why not use this method ?